# iOS cam zoom factors

Tags: ios

I'd like to show zoom factors in my video app in the same way the iOS native app does. Opposed to the options shown in the iOS cam app, a call to `AVCaptureDevice.virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors` returns factors starting at 1.0 for "full field of view". It looks like there is a device specific magic factor to map virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors factors to options in the UI:

| device | options cam app | virtualDeviceSwitchOverVideoZoomFactors | magic factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone X | 1, 2 | (1), 1.799 | 1.11 |
| iPhone 11 Pro Max | 0.5, 1, 2 | (1), 2, 4 | 0.5 |
| iPhone 12 Pro Max | 0.5, 1, 2.5 | (1), 2, 5 | 0.5 |

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to hard code the magic factor in my app? I'd rather do not... Otherwise I need to run this through a maintenance cycle every time Apple releases some new angle / zoom option.

Comment: Hey! did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I check against availability of AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInUltraWideCamera, AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera and AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTelephotoCamera and add 0.5, 1.0, 2.0 accordingly. In case the video device's activeFormat has a fieldOfView < 34.0, I replace 2.0 by 2.5. This is kind of half hard coded and needs to be maintained.

Answer (score 2):

I had a virtual lab with the AVFoundation team at WWDC yesterday, and besides pointing me to this post, they confirmed that the iPhone X is an outlier. They told me that in all other cases the 0.5 factor is correct.

Comment: I'm assuming this applies to GSM as well as CDMA iPhone X devices. True? Also, do you know if the iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR are also outliers?

Comment: I don’t know about GSM vs. CDMA but I _assume_ it would be true of both. The code I wrote to deal with the differences in X models uses the 1.11 factor for the X, 1.0 for the XS and XS Max, and 0.5 for everything else. I don’t remember how I decided on 1.0 for the XS Max, but I used to own, and tested on, a XS. So it looks like it was a combination of taking the word of the Apple engineers and some hands-on experimentation. Obviously the safest course would be to test on actual hardware yourself.